# Wait onLocationChanged(Location location)

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, location, google-maps-android-api-2

I need to get current location, and after that - do next code. How can i wait while this method has finished? onLocationChanged is called automatically that why i have problem. Do someone has any ideas how to do itmore correct? 
I make it very stupid, in `OnLocationChanged()` i call `onResume()`, but it is so bad idea.

```
    @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    final Location loc = location;

    Log.d("myLogs", "OnChange2");
    Log.d("myLogs", "2" + loc.getLatitude() + "," + loc.getLongitude());
    myLat = loc.getLatitude();
    myLong = location.getLongitude();
    onResume();

}
```

Comment: You should not call onResume.  What do you want to have happen when the location changes?

Comment: i must get coordinates from there, and work with it in onResume()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use `AsyncTask` for that. See [Android find GPS location once, show loading dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486055/android-find-gps-location-once-show-loading-dialog) for the answers. Basically in `onPreExecute` you can start dialog( it starts before the `doInBackground` is called). It means you are waiting till the time you can location and showing the dialog. Then in `doInBackground` you can get the location. After that finishes `onPostExecute` is called. You can stop is from inside `onPostExecute`. You can check if the location is not null and then call some other function from inside `onPostExecute` also if you want.

This might be one way. You can learn a basic example from [AsyncTask Android example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example) . You can also start by reading the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and read [How to Get GPS Location Using AsyncTask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035231/how-to-get-gps-location-using-asynctask) .

Some other similar helpful questions:

[Wait for current location - GPS - Android Dev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538389/wait-for-current-location-gps-android-dev)

[getting location instantly in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002630/getting-location-instantly-in-android)

Hope this helps.

Comment: i think i must learn AsyncTask, but now what is more simple solution?

Comment: I think sometime or the other if you would be helpful for you. It is straight forward. You can try to start with 3 basic functions doInBackground , onPreExecute  and onPostExecute.  onPreExecute   is called just before starting background process. Things inside doInBackground  are run in background thread. onPostExecute is run after the background process.

Comment: Ok, but  
 1. In what thread onLocationChange() is running and where it started. 
 2 How can i do onLocationChange () in background if this method is calling by system?

Comment: You can request for location updates from inside your `doInbackground` using `requestLocationUpdates` like: `LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
                LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();  
                mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);`

Answer (score 0):

I realize the OP has accepted the above answer but I have a feeling the OP wanted a more simple answer.

I am assuming the OP has an android application with an Activity.  I declared mine like this:

```
public class HelloAndroidActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
```

The OP was confused as to how the lifecycle methods worked and when work should be done.  My Resume and Pause methods would look like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    ((LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE)).removeUpdates(this);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    ((LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE)).requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5 * 1000, 1, this);
    super.onResume();
}
```

Notice that my onResume asks that I be notified when there are location updates and the onPause method asks that I no longer be notified.  You should be careful to not ask for updates at a time interval smaller then you really need or you will drain your battery.

Since the activity implements LocationListener my onLocationChanged method looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // Update the location fields
    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.latField)).setText(Double.toString(location.getLatitude()));
    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.longField)).setText(Double.toString(location.getLongitude()));
}
```

This simply takes the new location and updates some text EditText fields that I have in my activity.  The only other thing I needed to do was to add the GPS permission to my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

So if I were asking how to start out using the location manager and the location service this would be how I would begin.  I'm not trying to take anything away from the accepted answer, I just think there was a fundamental misunderstanding about what to do in onResume and in the onLocationMethodChanged methods.